# What happens when deleting the windows event log file at C:\Windows\System32\winevt\Logs?

Tags: windows-10

What happens when deleting the windows event log file at `C:\Windows\System32\winevt\Logs`?
In `C:\Windows\System32\winevt\Logs` there are a lot of log files that are logged by windows. what happens when i delete all these log files?
I am using windows10.

Comment: The more important question is, why do you want to remove them?

Answer (score 0):

Not all of the `C:\Windows\System32\winevt\Logs\*.evtx` files are currently in use. This depends on your Windows configuration.

###### 1. File not in use:

You can delete the file and it will stay vanished until an event will be written to this event log.

###### 2. File in use:

You will not be able to delete it as it is in use. So nothing happens except the "file in use" error message.

To delete this file, you either would have to make Windows stop logging the activities written to this file or you would have to boot a separate OS so Windows is not active in the moment of deletion.

###### Ergo:

- When trying to delete such a file within the running Windows, you would only miss log information of stopped log activities (so probably not of interest anymore).
- Active logs cannot be deleted this way, so no data loss is to be expected.
- Preferably you should do log content management within your event-viewer and policies as expected by the Windows developers.